# How do I turn this series of dataframes into a time series in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data which is received daily:

1/1/2013

```
In [8]: thePrices
Out[8]: 
         ADM7C 77.0 Curncy   ADM7P 76.5 Curncy   AUDUSD Curncy 
PX_ASK                1.36                1.04          0.7724
PX_BID                1.35                1.02          0.7723
PX_LAST               1.35                1.08          0.7724
```

1/2/2013

```
In [8]: thePrices
Out[8]: 
         ADM7C 77.0 Curncy   ADM7P 76.5 Curncy   AUDUSD Curncy 
PX_ASK                1.36                1.04          0.7724
PX_BID                1.34                1.00          0.7723
PX_LAST               1.35                1.03          0.7724
```

I want to create a time series in the following form:

```
         ADM7C 77.0 Curncy         ADM7P 76.5 Curncy        AUDUSD Curncy
         PX_ASK  PX_BID  PX_LAST   PX_ASK  PX_BID  PX_LAST  PX_ASK  PX_BID  PX_LAST
1/1/2013   1.36    1.04     1.35     1.04    1.04     1.08  0.7724  0.7723   0.7724
1/2/2013   1.36    1.34     1.35     1.04    1.00     1.03  0.7723  0.7723   0.7724
```

How does one dew this?

EDIT:

I guess just show me how to do one, and I can figure out how to combine them. To be more explicit, how do i go from this:

```
         ADM7C 77.0 Curncy   ADM7P 76.5 Curncy   AUDUSD Curncy 
PX_ASK                1.36                1.04          0.7724
PX_BID                1.35                1.02          0.7723
PX_LAST               1.35                1.08          0.7724
```

To this:

```
         ADM7C 77.0 Curncy         ADM7P 76.5 Curncy        AUDUSD Curncy
         PX_ASK  PX_BID  PX_LAST   PX_ASK  PX_BID  PX_LAST  PX_ASK  PX_BID  PX_LAST
1/1/2013   1.36    1.04     1.35     1.04    1.04     1.08  0.7724  0.7723   0.7724
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of data frames, you can provide a key as the dates while doing the concatenation and then `unstack` the original index to columns:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['1/1/2013', '1/2/2013']).unstack(level=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was working through an unstack example, and got a working bit, but yours is much more elegant. Though, to do a single frame, I am going to use a bastard version of yours: `pd.concat([thePrices], keys=[dt.strftime(todayDate, format = '%m/%d/%Y')]).unstack(level=1)` Is there a better way? (I.e. - I am using 'concat' unnecessarily, to get the shape I want.)